# Find unrelated partitions of a complete binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have a complete binary tree of height 'h'.
How do I find 'h' number of unrelated partitions for this ?

NOTE:
Unrelated partition means no child can be present with its immediate parent.

There is a constraint on the number of nodes in each partition.
The difference of the maximum number nodes in a partition and the minimum number of nodes in the partition can either be 0 or 1.

Also, root is excluded from including in the partitions.

Comment: what is `h` for a complete tree with 7 nodes?

Comment: @WalterTross `h` is 2 for a complete binary tree with 7 nodes.  
Considering root node is at `h` = 0

Comment: Why is this tagged with both java and python?

Comment: anyway, if by partition you mean a set of nodes, not constrained by their number, then your condition for unrelated partitions can easily be satisfied by having the root belong to the same partition as the leaves, and every layer in between belong to a different partition

Comment: Seems like there's no answer for n=3, h=1. Other than that, I agree with the comment by @WalterTross. You just need to do a level-order traversal, and put each level into a partition.

Comment: @WalterTross There is a constraint on the number of nodes in each partition.
The difference of the maximum number nodes in a partition and the minimum number of nodes in the partition can either be 0 or 1.

Comment: @AnujShenoy you should write that in your question! If that's what you mean by balance index, I don't think it's clear enough

Comment: @user3386109 Can you put this up in a pseudo code for better understanding?

Comment: @WalterTross You have 1 partition (that's true)  ... but it includes the immediate parent of both children.

Comment: @user3386109 you are right, sorry. But anyway, the original question was more complicated...

Comment: @user3386109 root is excluded from including in the partitions.

Comment: @AnujShenoy this is an extra condition, this question is evolving all the time...

Comment: @WalterTross Final this is. Promise no more changes.

Comment: A level-order traversal is just a breadth-first search (BFS) starting from the root. [Pseudocode for a BFS is here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode).

Comment: @user3386109 how do I keep the balance index condition satisfied whilst creating partition for each level ?

Comment: I was responding to the comment you posted before you added that constraint to the problem. Separating the nodes into levels is the first step towards a solution. Alternating levels and alternating sides are the two options you have for avoiding children with their immediate parents. [Here's a simple example for n=31](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVtr2.png). This example is nice and clean, because you need 7 or 8 nodes in each partition. It isn't always that simple. I think if you figure out how to solve n=63, you'll have a good understanding of what you need for the general case.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for the insight... I'll build up on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who devised the problem probably had a more elegant solution in mind, but the following works.

Let's say we have `h` partitions numbered `1` to `h`, and that the nodes of partition `n` have value `n`. The root node has value `0`, and does not participate in the partitions. Let's call a partition even if `n`is even, and odd if `n` is odd. Let's also number the levels of the complete binary tree, ignoring the root and starting from level `1` with 2 nodes. Level `n` has 2<sup>n</sup> nodes, and the complete tree has 2<sup>h+1</sup>-1 nodes, but only P=2<sup>h+1</sup>-2 nodes belong to the partitions (because the root is excluded). Each partition consists of p=⌊P/h⌋ or p=⌈P/h⌉ nodes, such that ∑ᵢpᵢ=P.

If the height `h` of the tree is even, put all even partitions into the even levels of the left subtree and the odd levels of the right subtee, and put all odd partitions into the odd levels of the left subtree and the even levels of the right subtree.

If `h` is odd, distribute all partitions up to partition `h-1` like in the even case, but distribute partition `h` evenly into the last level of the left and right subtrees.

This is the result for `h` up to 7 (I wrote a tiny [Python library to print binary trees](https://github.com/waltertross/basicbintree) to the terminal in a compact way for this purpose):

```
 0
1 1
```

```
   0
 1   2
2 2 1 1
```

```
       0
   1       2
 2   2   1   1
1 1 3 3 2 2 3 3
```

```
               0
       1               2
   2       2       1       1
 1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2
2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

```
                               0
               1                               2
       2               2               1               1
   1       1       1       1       2       2       2       2
 2   2   2   2   2   2   4   4   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   3
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

```
                                                               0
                               1                                                               2
               2                               2                               1                               1
       1               1               1               1               2               2               2               2
   2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
 1   1   1   1   1   1   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   2   2   2   2   2   2   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

```
                                                                                                                               0
                                                               1                                                                                                                               2
                               2                                                               2                                                               1                                                               1
               1                               1                               1                               1                               2                               2                               2                               2
       2               2               2               2               2               2               2               2               1               1               1               1               1               1               1               1
   1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2       2
 2   2   2   2   2   2   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

And this is the code that generates it:

````py
from basicbintree import Node

for h in range(1, 7 + 1):
    root = Node(0)
    P = 2 ** (h + 1) - 2  # nodes in partitions
    p = P // h  # partition size (may be p or p + 1)
    if h & 1:  # odd height
        t = (p + 1) // 2  # subtree tail nodes from split partition
        n = (h - 1) // 2  # odd or even partitions in subtrees except tail
    else:  # even height
        t = 0  # no subtree tail nodes from split partition
        n = h // 2  # odd or even partitions in subtrees
    s = P // 2 - t  # subtree nodes excluding tail
    r = s - n * p  # partitions of size p + 1 in subtrees
    x = [p + 1] * r + [p] * (n - r)  # nodes indexed by subtree partition - 1
    odd  = [1 + 2 * i for i, c in enumerate(x) for _ in range(c)] + [h] * t
    even = [2 + 2 * i for i, c in enumerate(x) for _ in range(c)] + [h] * t
    for g in range(1, h + 1):
        start = 2 ** (g - 1) - 1
        stop = 2 ** g - 1
        if g & 1:  # odd level
            root.set_level(odd[start:stop] + even[start:stop])
        else:  # even level
            root.set_level(even[start:stop] + odd[start:stop])
    print('```none')
    root.print_tree()
    print('```')
````

All trees produced up to height 27 have been programmatically confirmed to meet the specifications.

Some parts of the algorithm would need a proof, like, e.g., that it's always possible to choose an even size for the split partition in the odd height case, but this and other proofs are left as an exercise to the reader ;-)